# What is the proper way of passing pointers to arrays in C?

Tags: c, c99, clang-static-analyzer

Take this piece of code as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_array(size_t size, unsigned (*myarray)[])
{
    printf("Array size: %lu\n", size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            printf("%u ", (*myarray)[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main() {
    unsigned myarray[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
    print_array(sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(unsigned), &myarray);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with clang analyzer (via gcc 10.1.0) the warning is:

```
src/main.c:7:3: warning: 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value
            printf("%u ", (*myarray)[i]);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The output is:

```
Array size: 5
9 8 7 6 5
```

What is the mistake in this piece of code and what is the proper way to pass pointers to arrays in C?

Comment: Can you give the command used to compile ?

Comment: Looks like you compile it as c++ not c

Comment: Probably clang analyzer checks only current function, but not it's calls. There is no initialization of _unsigned (*myarray)[]_ in current function, so analyzer throws warinig

Comment: Arrays _decay_ to pointers to the element composing them. So `void print_array(size_t size, unsigned *myarray)` will be ok. You could call it with ` print_array(sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(unsigned), myarray);`. (some modifications are required in `print_array` implementation too, accordingly)

Comment: The command I used to compile it was
`/usr/bin/../lib/clang/ccc-analyzer -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra src/main.c -o test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a false positive. There is no problem with the code - although the style is a bit exotic, it is all valid C.

If the remark is about actual missing initialization, it could be related to the tool not checking the caller. But even if the analyser only takes the local translation unit in consideration, it can't go off and assume that passed variables are uninitialized by default. That would be a very strange assumption.

Perhaps the analyser got spooked that you are actually passing a `unsigned (*myarray)[5]` to a function expecting a `unsigned (*myarray)[]` (pointer to incomplete type, an array of unspecified size). You could try to change the parameter to `unsigned (*myarray)[size])` and see if it makes the tool happier.

Edit: the array pointer types are compatible though, so the tool shouldn't complain for that reason either. As per C17 6.7.6.2/6, one or both of the array types can leave out the size specifier and still be compatible:

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value.

Comment: Passing a complete pointer to array type does indeed silence the warning.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński Curious! I don't really know if a pointer to array of incomplete type is to be regarded as compatible with a pointer to array of fixed size. I suspect not, but the C standard is vague. It mentions some things regarding how to deal with incomplete array types part of a function declaration, but this here is a function definition.

Comment: The pointer types are compatible per C 2018 6.7.6.2 6. Note that the array type without size **is** an incomplete type; it is not an array **of** an incomplete type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok so one or both of the array types can leave out the array size and they will be compatible. Doesn't explain why the static analyser gives a warning still, then. I'll add a note about array compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass a pointer and use the fact that array variables represent the address where their first element starts.
It seems using pedantic with clang, makes a lot of assumptions about what *could* the function argument be pointing to, so it complains.

```
void print_array(size_t size, const unsigned *myarray)
{
    printf("Array size: %lu\n", size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            printf("%u ", myarray[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    unsigned myarray[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
    print_array(sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(unsigned), myarray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C wordings, the array *decays* to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function.

Comment: Yes this code is much easier to read, but that doesn't explain the tool warning. (Also you should use const-correctness.)

Comment: Btw the question is "What is the proper way of passing pointers to arrays in C?" and this code is strictly speaking not doing that - it is passing a pointer to the first element.

Comment: What bugs me is that in this version when passing a unsigned *ptr = NULL as myarray there will be no warning, while in the version I presented there will be a warning.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for spotting the `const`. Modified my answer.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: “Decays” is not standard C wording; it is a colloquial usage.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question asked and should not be up-voted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thank you for the remark. I used standard when I meant *common*. As English is not my first language I could not find colloquial which is certainly much better.